# How to change Firebase notification account on React Native iOS project?

Tags: firebase, react-native, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to change Firebase account in my project for notification. I did it for Android. I created a new account and took googleService.json, then replaced the old version. It worked for Android, but when I did it the same way for iOS it did not work. Test Notification was not received on my iOS device.

Comment: Please add some code snippets of your implementation. This will help solve your question more efficiently.

Comment: as @chiril.sarajiu writes, please provide some more information. Read [ask] for information about how to write a good, answerable question.